# Delete consecutive duplicates from a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database , where table contains consecutive duplicate rows . Demo of table with data is as follows.

```
id  name  processed
 1  xyz      0
 2  xyz      0
 3  ABC      0
 4  ABC      0
```

I want to delete the consecutive duplicate from this table , and once duplicate is deleted update processed to 1. So that the final table looks like follows.

```
id  name  processed
 1  xyz      1
 3  ABC      1
```

I am doing it as follow.

```
SET @v1 := (select group_concat(`id`) from `names` as m1 where 0 < (select count(*) from `names` as m2 where m2.`id` = m1.`id` - 1 and m2.`name` = m1.`name`));
DELETE FROM names WHERE id IN (@v1);
UPDATE names SET `processed`=1 WHERE `processed`=0
```

The query works fine , but it deletes one row at a time . Please help me on this.I want all the selected rows to be deleted .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DELETE FROM table WHERE name=name and id>id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **PHP** and **MySQL**, If your all data is consecutive pairs then this will work.

```
$con = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$query ="select m1.id from names as m1 where 0 < (select count(*) from names as m2 where m2.id = m1.id - 1 and m2.name = m1.name)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $query2 ="DELETE FROM names WHERE id = ".$row['id'];
  mysqli_query($con, $query2);
  $id = $row['id']-1;
  $query3 ="UPDATE names SET `processed`=1 WHERE id = ".$id;
  mysqli_query($con, $query3);
}
```

I checked it and its working fine. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

As @MarkBaker already wrote in comment, you can try `DELETE FROM table WHERE name=name and id>id`.

But that's only fix to what already has been done. To **prevent** that, you should add `unique` index to `name` column. That should prevent any duplicates of being added in future.

You can't set `unique` index when you have duplicates though, so you need clean first :)

Comment: This is fine , but I also need to update processed value after deleting duplicates . And don't you think this way query will take much time than to compare consecutive rows ? As I know that duplicates are always consecutive . Data is coming out from some where , I only have database . So what you suggested I can not implement .

Answer (score 1):

You cannot UPDATE and DELETE in the same query. So that pretty much leaves you with this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE  TABLE my_table 
(id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,name  CHAR(3) NOT NULL,processed TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1  ,'xyz',      0),
(2  ,'xyz',      0),
(3  ,'ABC',      0),
(4  ,'ABC',      0);

SELECT * FROM my_Table;
+----+------+-----------+
| id | name | processed |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | xyz  |         0 |
|  2 | xyz  |         0 |
|  3 | ABC  |         0 |
|  4 | ABC  |         0 |
+----+------+-----------+

SELECT y.* FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.id = x.id + 1 AND y.name = x.name;
+----+------+-----------+
| id | name | processed |
+----+------+-----------+
|  2 | xyz  |         0 |
|  4 | ABC  |         0 |
+----+------+-----------+

DELETE y FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.id = x.id + 1 AND y.name = x.name;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)


UPDATE my_table SET processed = 1;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+-----------+
| id | name | processed |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | xyz  |         1 |
|  3 | ABC  |         1 |
+----+------+-----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

This will not edit your table, but will give you SELECT with desired result:

```
SELECT min(id) id, name, 1 processed
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name
```

You can use this in `CREATE TABLE newtable AS SELECT ...`, and then `DROP mytable`, and finally to `ALTER TABLE newtable RENAME TO mytable`.

Answer (score -1):

The `DISTINCT` keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.
Use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `id`, `name`,`1` AS processed
FROM mytable;
```